# Is there a way to read a line backwards in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to write a program that counts the number of N's at the end of a string. 
I have a file containing a many lines of unique sequences and I want to measure how often the sequence ends with N, and how long the series of N's are. For example, the file input will look like this:

```
NTGTGTAATAGATTTTACTTTTGCCTTTAAGCCCAAGGTCCTGGACTTGAAACATCCAAGGGATGGAAAATGCCGTATAACNN
NAAAGTCTACCAATTATACTTAGTGTGAAGAGGTGGGAGTTAAATATGACTTCCATTAATAGTTTCATTGTTTGGAAAACAGN
NTACGTTTAGTAGAGACAGTGTCTTGCTATGTTGCCCAGGCTGGTCTCAAACTCCTGAGCTCTAGCAAGCCTTCCACCTCNNN
NTAATCCAACTAACTAAAAATAAAAAGATTCAAATAGGTACAGAAAACAATGAAGGTGTAGAGGTGAGAAATCAACAGGANNN
```

Ideally, the code will read through the file, line by line and count how often a line ends with 'N'.

Then, if a line ends with N, it should read each character backwards to see how long the string of N's is. This information will be used to calculate the percentage of lines ending in N, as well as the mean, mode, median and range of N strings.
Here is what I have so far.

```
filename = 'N_strings_test.txt'

n_strings = 0
n_string_len = []
with open(filename, 'r') as in_f_obj:
    line_count = 0
    for line in in_f_obj:  
        line_count += 1
        base_seq = line.rstrip()  
        if base_seq[-1] == 'N':
            n_strings += 1
            if base_seq[-2] == 'N':
                n_string_len.append(int(2))
            else:
                n_string_len.append(int(1))
print(line_count)
print(n_strings)
print(n_string_len)
```

All i'm getting is an index out of range error, but I don't understand why. Also, what I have so far is only limited to 2 characters.

I want to try and write this for myself, so I don't want to import any modules.

Thanks.

Comment: This should be pretty easy, lemme finish the code.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably get the `IndexError` because your file has empty lines!

---

Two sound approaches. First the generic one: iterate the line in reverse using `reversed()`:

```
line = line.rstrip()
count = 0
for c in reversed(line):
    if c != 'N':
        break
    count += 1

# count will now contain the number of N characters from the end
```

Another, even easier, which does modify the string, is to `rstrip()` all whitespace, get the length, and then `rstrip()` all `N`s. The number of trailing `N`s is the difference in lengths:

```
without_whitespace = line.rstrip()
without_ns = without_whitespace .rstrip('N')
count = len(without_whitespace) - len(without_ns)
```

Comment: The file may have empty lines in it, but the files are very large, so I cannot manually delete them, is there away around this index error? I'm already using `rstrip()` on each line, and even when altering to `rstrip('\n')`, I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This code is:

- Reading line by line
- Reversing the string and `lstrip`ing it. Reversing is not necessary but it make things natural.
- Read last character, if N then increment
- Keep reading that line until we have stream of N

```
n_string_count, n_string_len, line_count = 0, [], 0
with open('file.txt', 'r') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        line_count += 1
        line = line[::-1].lstrip()
        if line:
            if line[0] == 'N':
                n_string_count += 1
                consecutive_n = 1
                while consecutive_n < len(line)  and line[consecutive_n] == 'N': consecutive_n += 1
                n_string_len.append(consecutive_n)
print(line_count)
print(n_string_count)
print(n_string_len)
```